# What data structure is good for maintaining file paths?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on the ["Longest Absolute filepath"](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-absolute-file-path/description/) problem on LeetCode.  This is a simple problem that asks "What is the length of the longest absolute file path in a given directory". And my working solution is as follows. The file directory is given as a string.

```
def lengthLongestPath(self, input):
    """
    :type input: str, the file directory
    :rtype: int
    """

    current_folder_path = [""] * 40
    longest_file_path_size = 0

    for item in input.split("\n"):

        num_tabs = item.count("\t")
        print num_tabs
        if "." not in item:
            current_folder_path[num_tabs] = item.lstrip("\t")
        else:
            absolute_file_path = "/".join(current_folder_path[:num_tabs] + [item.lstrip("\t")]) 
            print item
            print num_tabs, absolute_file_path, current_folder_path
            longest_file_path_size = max(len(absolute_file_path), longest_file_path_size)

    return longest_file_path_size
```

This works. However, note that on line `current_folder_path = [""] * 40` is very unelegant. This was a line to remember the current file path. I wonder if there is a way to remove this.

Comment: We need a way to know what the current folder path so far is.

Comment: your solution isn't O(n) anyway. So for solving the problem you'll need to store only the lengths in some array. In which case it's not required to store the paths in some data structures. Do you still want the way of doing that?

Comment: Wouldn't `sorted(os.listdir(path), key=len)[-1]` suffice? Nevermind I didn't read your question thoroughly.

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh My solution is O(N) in time. I'm not sure how you deduced that it was any higher.

Comment: @afc11hn This is a competitive programming question.

Comment: @彼得名姓 Okay I didn't look at it closely, it is indeed O(n).

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement does not address some fine points. It is very unclear what path may correspond to the string

```
a\n\t\tb
```

Is it `a//b` or plain illegal? If the former, do we need to normalize it?

I guess it is safe to assume that such paths are illegal. In other words, the path depth only grows by 1, and the `current_folder_path` in fact functions like a stack. You don't need to preinitialize it, but just push the name when `num_tabs` exceeds its size, and pop as necessary.

As a side note, since `join` is linear to the current accumulated length, the entire algorithm seems quadratic, which violates the time complexity requirement.

Comment: Hm, could you suggest a data structure to replace my 40 length array? I'm not sure I can think of one --- perhaps an Ordered Default Dict?

Comment: A simple list shall suffice. Just make it a list of integers (lengths of corresponding names), and maintain a running tally.